# How to change text in text area with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

> I want to change the text written in textarea with react hooks. But I have problem with reading text from text area.

```
const uCyr = function uCyr() {
var entered_text;
entered_text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
entered_text = entered_text.replace(/a/g, "b");
document.getElementById("textarea").style.color = "#9C27B0";
document.getElementById("textarea").value = entered_text;
};
```

export default uCyr;

[Link sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ucirl-xw666?file=/src/Ucyr.js:0-309)

Comment: this is vanilla JS code, that has nothing to do with React. And in general you shouldn't mix this style of code, with `document.getElementById` and so on, with React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will do most things inline for React values and use onChange handlers to update them.

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");

<textarea className="textarea" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
```

If you make a state for the textarea value and then use the second line as your jsx for the textarea, it should  work.